# Is there a lift of the q-Vandermonde identity to some geometric (motivic) identity for Grassmannians over $F_q$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, grassmannians, field-with-one-element, q-analogs

The [q-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Vandermonde_identity) reads:

$$ \binom{m + n}{k}_{\!\!q} =\sum_{j} \binom{m}{k - j}_{\!\!q} \binom{n}{j}_{\!\!q} q^{j(m-k+j)} $$

The [q-binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient): 
$$ \binom{ a }{ b}_{\!\!q} $$

are known to count the number of points over the Grassmannians $Gr(a,b)$ over $F_q$, and $q^{j(m-k+j)}$ is the number of points over $A^{j(m-k+j)}$ over $F_q$.

So the identity above states that number of points of $Gr(k, m+n)$ can be written as the sum of numbers of points of smaller Grassmannians and $A^l$.
That would be naturally explained if there would be some geometric relation between these manifolds, like fiber bundles.

**Question 1** What could be the geometric interpretation of the identity above, if any? If yes, what about other fields, e.g. $C$?

**Question 2** Is the identity above true on the level of motives?

**Question 2b** If yes, then is it true for arbitrary fields?

---

For the case of q=1 - the hypothetical ["field with one element"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element),
everything is "Okay": the $Gr(a,b,F_1)$ are just the sets of all  a-combinations out of b and so the usual Vandermonde identity implies that $Gr(m+n,k)$ can be factorized in terms of smaller Grassmannians. That is, however, a kind of cheating, since over $F_1$, geometry disappears and counting is enough to give a "geometric" identity.

Comment: I remember trying to prove something like this identity in a comment on math.stackexchange using exact sequences, but I didn't have the time to go through the grueling details. But now I'm thinking that maybe it's easiest to forget about the coordinate-free Grassmannian and think of RREMs (= reduced row echelon matrices). A RREM with $n+m$ columns and $k$ rows can be regarded as a RREM with $n$ columns using only the first $j$ rows (for some $j \leq k$) attached to a RREM with $m$ columns using the remaining rows and an arbitrary $m \times j$-matrix. More precisely: ...

Comment: ... Any RREM with $n+m$ columns and $k$ rows can be written as a block matrix $\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ 0_{\left(k-j\right) \times n} & D \end{pmatrix}$, where $A$ is a RREM with $n$ columns and $j$ rows, where $D$ is a RREM with $m$ columns and $k-j$ rows, and where $B$ is a matrix whose columns above the pivots of $D$ are zero but whose entries are otherwise unconstrained (which leaves $q^{j\left(m-k+j\right)}$ options for $D$).

Comment: Obviously, this is a form of "cell decomposition" of the Grassmannian that holds over any field; I guess it can be defined invariantly using dimensions of intersections with another (fixed, $n$-dimensional) vector subspace, but don't quote me on that. I don't know what motives are (and from what I keep hearing, I am not sure if anyone does).

Comment: To some extent related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208560/q-catalan-numbers-from-grassmannians?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assume $V$ is a vector space of dimension $m+n$, $M \subset V$ is a subspace of dimension $m$, and $N = V/M$. Let $p:V \to N$ be the projection. Consider the Grassmannian $X = Gr(k,V)$ and its stratification by the dimension of intersection with $M$, i.e., set
$$
X_j = \{ U \in Gr(k,V) | \dim(U \cap M) = k - j \}.
$$
If $U \in X_k$ then the projection of $U$ to $N$ has dimension $j$. Thus, we have a natural map
$$
\pi \colon X_j \to Gr(k-j,M) \times Gr(j,N),\qquad U \mapsto (U \cap M,p(U)).
$$
Finally, for any $U_M \in Gr(k-j,M)$ and $U_N \in Gr(j,N)$ we have
$$
\pi^{-1}(U_M,U_N) \cong \{U' \in Gr(j,p^{-1}(U_N)/U_M) | U' \cap (U/U_M) = 0\}.
$$ 
This is an open Schubert cell, hence is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{j(m-k-j)}$. Moreover, the map $\pi$ is locally trivial, hence 
$$
[X_j] = [Gr(k-j,m)][Gr(j,n)][\mathbb{A}^{j(m-k-j)}]
$$
in the Grothendieck ring of varieties. Summing up over $j$, we obtain
$$
[Gr(k,m+n)] = \sum_j [Gr(k-j,m)][Gr(j,n)][\mathbb{A}^{j(m-k-j)}],
$$
a motivic version of the formula..

Comment: Very nice answer!