# Combinatorial/probabilistic statements having $F_{\text{un}}$/$F_q$ geometric interpetation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, field-with-one-element

$\newcommand{\Fun}{F_\text{un}}$There was lots of "Fun with $\Fun$"  ([field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element)) in recent years.
One of the points is that it provides bridge between geometrical and combinatorial questions, i.e. in the limit case $q=1$ geometry disappears and combinatorial structure distills, on the other hand looking through a $\Fun$ glass on combinatorics one may try to lift it to a geometric picture over $F_q$/any field.

My question is about giving examples of that kind.

**Question:**
What are some combinatorial/probabilistic  identities/concepts which have a nice $\Fun$  interpretation and might be lifted to nice geometric identities/concepts  over $F_q$/any field? Something similar to the example below:

---

**Example:**

(See [Is there a lift of the q-Vandermonde identity to some geometric (motivic) identity for Grassmannians over $F_q$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299581/is-there-a-lift-of-the-q-vandermonde-identity-to-some-geometric-motivic-identi?noredirect=1&lq=1))

***Combinatorial side:***

Consider the [Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity):
$$ \binom{m + n}{k} =\sum_{j} \binom{m}{k - j} \binom{n}{j}. $$

***Probability side:***
Consider $n+m$ balls, $m$ white, $n$ black,
what is the probability to choose $k-j$ white, $j$ black balls?
The answer is:
$$  \frac{  \binom{m}{k - j} \binom{n}{j} } { \binom{m + n}{k} }.  $$

And since the sum of probabilities over $j$ gives 1 we have the Vandermonde identity above.

***First $\Fun/F_q$ interpretation (projective geometry)***

**Interpretation:**
$\DeclareMathOperator\Gr{Gr}$According to $\Fun$-wisdom we should think about the Grassmanian when we see a
binomial coefficient:
$$\binom{n}{k} = \#( \Gr(k,n, \Fun) ). $$

Hence we might expect some geometric identity related to Grassmannians,
and indeed there is motivic identity which is true over any field:
$$
[\Gr(k,m+n)] = \sum_j [\Gr(k-j,m)][\Gr(j,n)] [\mathbb{A}^{j(m-k-j)}],
$$
as Sasha [explained](https://mathoverflow.net/a/299582).

On the level of enumeration of $F_q$-points it gives the [$q$-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Vandermonde_identity).

***Second interpretation (linear algebra)***

I am not sure that this interpretation is fully correct, but let me give it.
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$One of the curious things about $\Fun$ is that linear and projective geometry coincide over it. They should be different by $\GL(F_q)$ but over $\Fun$ it is just $1$  (at least I see it like that).

**Interpretation:**

$$ \binom{n}{k} = \# ( {\bigwedge}^k V^n(F_1)) = \dim ( {\bigwedge}^k V^n). $$

I mean that number of elements in a vector space coincide with its dimension over $\Fun$.

Now the Vandermonde identity can be interpreted like this:
consider  $V = V^{m} \oplus V^n$. Then

$$   {\bigwedge}^k V = \bigoplus_j {\bigwedge}^{k-j} V^m\otimes {\bigwedge}^{j}  V^{n}   $$

gives a lift from enumeration to isomorphism of objects (linear spaces)
which holds true not only over $\Fun$, but actually over any field.

---

Some similar  **examples**  can be found here:
[Can one divide algebraic manifolds ? Make sense: $Gr(2,n)/ Gr(2,n+m) = P^{n-1}/P^{n+m-1} P^{n-2}/P^{n+m-2}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299748/can-one-divide-algebraic-manifolds-make-sense-gr2-n-gr2-nm-pn-1-p)

---

As a reincarnation of Gjergji Zaimi's question [q-Catalan numbers from Grassmannians](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208560/q-catalan-numbers-from-grassmannians?noredirect=1&lq=1)
it is natural to ask a particular case of question 1:

**Question 2:** Can one give any $\Fun/F_q$ interpretation/lift of any identity related to Catalan numbers?

There are plenty of facts about the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), but it seems not obvious to interpret them geometrically. See Will Sawin's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208560/q-catalan-numbers-from-grassmannians#comment517485_208560) under the above mentioned  question
— the $q$-Catalan number itself is NOT the number of points of any smooth projective variety over $F_q$.

Comment: You say that the $q$-Catalan number itself is NOT the number of points of any smooth projective variety over $\mathbf{F}_q$. Which $q$-Catalan number do you mean? The $q$-Catalan number $c_n(0;q)$ of Problem A43(f) of my book *Catalan Numbers* has symmetric unimodal coefficients so could conceivably count points on a smooth projective variety over $\mathbf{F}_q$.

Comment: @RichardStanley I mean same q-Catalan as in Gjergji Zaimi question: $\frac{1}{[n+1]_q}\left[{2n\atop n}\right]_q$ . But any other suggestions are welcome. Is there any identity on any q-Catalan which can be lifted to geometric identity ?

Comment: There are probably things to be said about $[n]_q!$ as counting the number of points of the full flag variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$, but this is very closely related to, and generally more trivial than, than the case of Grasmannians

Answer (score 1):

The recent paper "Positroids, knots, and $q,t$-Catalan numbers" by Galashin and Lam (https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.09745) gives geometric meaning to the $q$-Catalan numbers (both kinds of $q$-Catalan numbers, in fact!).

Check out Corollary 1.3 for a specific probabilistic statement in line with your inquiry.

> We have the following elegant but baffling corollary.
>
> **Corollary 1.3.** The probability that a uniformly random $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ belongs to $\Pi_{k,n}^{\circ}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is given by $$\operatorname{Prob}(V \in \Pi_{k,n}^{\circ}(\mathbb{F}_q)) =\frac{(q-1)^n}{q^n-1}.$$
> The probability $\frac{(q-1)^n}{q^n-1}$ does not depend on $k$. We do not have a direct explanation for this phenomenon.

Here $\Pi_{k,n}^{\circ}(\mathbb{F})$ is the open positroid variety inside the Grassmannian $\operatorname{Gr}_{k,n}(\mathbb{F})$.